# Is there any alternative to the Canon Mount Adapter EF-EOS M?

Tags: lens-adapter, canon-m

I wonder if there is in the market any alternative adapter to [Canon Mount Adapter EF-EOS M](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/EF_Lenses/EF-M/Mount_Adapter_EF_EOS_M/). Reliable, and cheaper, that allow you use EOS lenses on EOS-M camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only alternative I have seen is from Fotodiox: [the EOS EF to EOS-M adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D9BKWEQ)

Currently, it's a pretty small market for EOS-M, so I wouldn't expect to see a whole lot of accessories for it.